# VBA Chart Positioning with a loop

Tags: vba, loops, charts, position

I have a loop creating 10 charts using Range Offset to increment 2 columns at a time.

The issue i have is the placement of each chart, currently they're stacking 10 charts on top of each other. Is there a way so each time the loop runs the chart position changes each time. Below is the code i currently have.

```
Sub charts()
'Set up the variables.
Dim rng As Range

'Use the InputBox dialog to set the range for MyFunction
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)


'Call MyFunction
ActiveCell.Value = MyFunction(rng)
End Sub

Function MyFunction(rng As Range) As Double

For i = 1 To 20 Step 2

Endrow = Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row - 1

Set Range1 = rng.Offset(Endrow, i + 1)

Sheets("All team charts").Select

MyFunction = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Team 1"
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Team 1"
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range1
With ActiveChart.Parent
     .height = 200 ' resize
     .width = 350  ' resize
     .top = 20    ' reposition
     .left = 20   ' reposition
 End With
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: You have lines labeled `reposition` in your code. Have you tried to make the position dependent on `i`? Also what is the purpose of `MyFunction`? It doesn't look like it would return anything other than 0.

Comment: Hi, I will try make them dependent on i and my function lets the under select the first range which is then offset

Comment: No, the inputbox lets the user choose the range that is then passed to the function. What is the function supposed to return (that you write to the active cell)?

Comment: i thought the function used the range which the user selected, applied it to the charts which i then offset and create the charts from?

Comment: yes it does that but you don't need a function for that. A function returns a value (for example the result of a calculation) and  setting a double to the `.Select` doesn't make sense. If you want to organize your code that way use a `Sub` instead. If you don't need it elsewhere, write it directly in the `Charts` sub

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you